# Cannot Update the SSD Firmware Using nvme-cli or msecli

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, firmware

I have a Micron SSD of model MTFDHAL800MCE on Mint 18.3. Using the tool msecli provided by Micron, I run the command `sudo msecli -F` to retrieve information regarding my SSD which is /dev/nvme0:

```
Device Name   FW-Rev
/dev/nvme0    0091634
/dev/sda      CC43
Firmware version retrieved successfully

CMD_STATUS   : Success 
STATUS_CODE  : 0 

Copyright (C) 2019 Micron Technology, Inc.
```

The frimware of my SSD is 0091634. I want to update this using the msecli or nvme-cli but I cannot find the latest version of firmware image file. I also tried the cli-user-guide infromation as below and ran the command `sudo msecli -F -U 0091634 -n /dev/nvme0` to download and update the firmware but I got the following error:

**CLI-USER-GUIDE INFORMATION**

> Downloading a Single Firmware Image.
>
> This option downloads a raw firmware binary image to the specified Micron drive. 
>   The optional -S
>    can be used to specify a firmware slot on an NVMe drive. If
>   -S is not specified for an NVMe drive, the slot will be chosen automatically.
>
> Usage: msecli -F [-U  | -S  |
>   -A] [-l] [-m ] -n  [ -r] [ -s  ]
>
> 1. Enter the following at the command prompt: msecli -F -U < firmware binary image > -n < devicename >
> 2. Confirm the operation when prompted. A message indicates the firmware image update is in progress. When finished, a message
>      indicates the operation was successful.

**Error**

```
Trying to update current firmware for /dev/nvme0. 
    Are you sure you want to continue(Y|N):y

Firmware update for /dev/nvme0 will take a few minutes to complete.
Please wait

Device Name  : /dev/nvme0
Firmware update operation failed
CMD_STATUS   : Invalid firmware image file 
STATUS_CODE  : 15 

Copyright (C) 2019 Micron Technology, Inc.
```

How can I update this firmware successfully?

Comment: This msecli program's documentation is mis-using the word "download".   What it should say is "upload" because the program **uploads** a firmware file (with option `-U <firmware binary image>`) from the linux host to the drive.  It does **not** cause the drive to download a firmware file and install it.  The faulty documentation is probably the source of your confusion about what it does.   @telcoM's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the `msecli` command does not contain the actual firmware. You would need another file containing the new firmware - `msecli` is just a tool for transferring the firmware to the SSD.

As you enter the command `sudo msecli -F -U 0091634 -n /dev/nvme0`, you're effectively saying: "Here in the current directory is a file named '0091634' which contains the new firmware for this SSD, please install it." If you don't in fact have a file named literally `0091634` present in the current directory, the command will obviously fail.

By Googling on your SSD model "MTFDHAL800MCE", I found [this datasheet for it](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/ssd/9100_hhhl_u_2_pcie_ssd.pdf). From the document title, the name of the SSD series seems to be "9100".

By going to the [Micron documentation/downloads page](https://www.micron.com/support#SupportDocumentationandDownloads) and selecting "Search Firmware", there seems to be just one firmware package for the 9100 series SSDs as of this writing. It is named [Firmware 1634.zip](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/software/nvme/9100-firmware/firmware-1634.zip).

The `Firmware 1634.zip` package contains two files: `Release Notes.txt` and `firmware.tar`. Here are the contents of the Release Notes:

```
v0.09.1634 Changes: 
        * Fix for journal log error and overlay bug.
        * OPROM file is now signed
        * Update the UEFI OPROM to the UDK2014 stable release.
        * Fix SMART warning in NVMe-MI
        * Fix clean power cycle issue
        * Fix the command timeout time from 100ms to 200ms
ERRATA:

A compatibility issue exists in firmware version 1634 with VPD enabled.
If upgrading to firmware version 1634, VPD cannot be enabled.  
If VPD functionality is required, please contact your Micron
representative for guidance on how to enable VPD.

INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS:

Micron Storage Executive:
    1) Command:  msecli -F -U firmware.tar -n <NVMe Device Path> 
    2) Cold Power Cycle Host
    Example:  msecli -F -U firmware.tar -n /dev/nvme0
```

So, the full version number is `v0.09.1634`... and the numbers in there are an exact match to the `0091634` reported by your `msecli` tool. It looks like this firmware version is what you already have, so no upgrade is needed.

The Release Notes file also shows the exact `msecli` command to use when installing the new firmware, indicating that the `firmware.tar` inside the package is the file that should be given to the `msecli` tool.

Comment: yes, I think it is like what you say. But the next problem is that I cannot even find the latest version of the firmware to download

Comment: By Googling on your SSD model "MTFDHAL800MCE", I found [this datasheet for it](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/ssd/9100_hhhl_u_2_pcie_ssd.pdf). From the document title, the name of the SSD series is "9100". By going to [Micron documentation/downloads page](https://www.micron.com/support#SupportDocumentationandDownloads) and "Search Firmware", the available firmware for 9100 SSDs is [version 1634](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/software/nvme/9100-firmware/firmware-1634.zip) - the version you seem to already have?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that a firmware version newer than 1634 even exists for your SSD model?

Comment: Thanks, I have got confused with the Micron website and its documents :))
But using the command mentioned in the question, the version of my firmware is 0091634 not 1634.

Comment: I've downloaded the "1634" firmware package and read the Release Notes.txt inside it. It indicates the full version is v0.09.1634, which would seem to match the "0091634" reported by the `msecli` tool. I guess the initial 0.09 may be identifying the firmware for the 9100 series, and 1634 the version, and the confusing short naming is just Micron employees' internal shorthand leaking out to public documents :-/

Comment: Ohhhh... what a good information you provided. I do appreciate. So, you mean this file is the updated firmware file to be given to the msecli tool or the one I already have and no update is required?

Comment: Both :) The package has two files: `Release Notes.txt` and `firmware.tar`. The Release Notes file indicates the `firmware.tar` is the file to be given to the `msecli` tool: it even gives a detailed example. And by the version numbers, it looks like you already have the latest firmware that is publicly available, so no update is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help